# How to use HTML parser to get whats in a div tag or another tag in Java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I want to get text in a tag, i.e

```
<div id="title">    MotoGP  </div>
```

I want to extract "MotoGP" from here.
I'm using `org.htmlparser`.

I've tried

```
NodeList nodes = parser.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("div"),
     new HasAttributeFilter("id", "title")));

    SimpleNodeIterator nodeIterator = nodes.elements();
    while (nodeIterator.hasMoreNodes()) {

             HeadingTag tag = (HeadingTag)node;
             System.out.println(tag.getStringText());
```

Comment: NodeList nodes = parser.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("div"),
             new HasAttributeFilter("id", "title")));
            SimpleNodeIterator nodeIterator = nodes.elements();
            while (nodeIterator.hasMoreNodes()) {
   // Node node = nodeIterator.nextNode();
                     HeadingTag tag = (HeadingTag)node;
                     System.out.println(tag.getStringText());

Comment: I've edited my question and pasted my code. .  it is not working

Comment: it does not return data between divs

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something like this:

```
Parser p;

// initialize p somehow
p = createParser(html /* actual html String */,
    charset /* null for default */);

NodeList nl = p.extractAllNodesThatMatch(
    new HasAttributeFilter("id", "title")); // or other id...

// if you want the text of the 1st matching node:
System.out.println(nl.elementAt(0).getText());
```

See especially:

- [Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Parser.html)
- [Parser.extractAllNodesThatMatch()](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Parser.html#extractAllNodesThatMatch%28org.htmlparser.NodeFilter%29)
- [Node.getText()](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Node.html#getText%28%29)